# Python ORM to NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, orm, pytables, column-oriented

I am building data simulation framework with numpy ORM, where it is much more convenient to work with classes and objects instead of numpy arrays directly. Nevertheless, **output of the simulation should be numpy array**. Also blockz is quite interesting as a backend here.

I would like to map all object attributes to numpy arrays. Thus, numpy arrays work like a column-oriented "persistent" storage for my classes. I also need to link "new" attributes to objects which I can calculate using numpy(pandas) framework. And then just link them to objects accordingly using the same back-end.

Is there any solution for such approach? Would you recommend any way to build it in a HPC way?
I have found only django-pandas. PyTables is quite slow on adding new columns-attributes.

Something like (working on pointers to np_array):

```
class Instance()
    def __init__(self, np_array, np_position):
        self.np_array = np_array
        self.np_position = np_position

    def get_test_property():
        return(self.np_array[np_position])

    def set_test_property(value):
        self.np_array[np_position] = value
```

Comment: I would use pandas dataframes as much as possible. Might you be reinventing the wheel somewhat?

Comment: @Mr E, So far I haven't find anyway to map values from pandas Series to object attributes. Am I missing something?

Comment: I meant, can you use a [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) instead of writing your own class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact there is a way to change NumPy or bcolz arrays by reference.
Simple example can be found in the following code.

```
a = np.arange(10)
class Case():
    def __init__(self, gcv_pointer):
        self.gcv = gcv_pointer

    def gcv(self):
        return(self.gcv)

    def gcv_set(self, value):
        self.gcv[:] = value
pass
#===============================================================================
# NumPy
#===============================================================================
caseList = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    case = Case(a[i-1:i])
    caseList.append(case)
gcvs = [case.GetGCV() for case in caseList]
caseList[1].SetGCV(5)
caseList[1].SetGCV(13)
caseList[1].gcv[:] = 6

setattr(caseList[1], 'dpd', a[5:6])

caseList[1].dpd
caseList[1].dpd[:] = 888
```